# Regex with negative lookbehind and unknown mid-section PHP

Tags: php, regex, url

When performing a preg_match in PHP I'm using the following regex:

`/\/(bp|s)?\d+\//`

This correctly matches the following strings:

1. `/v/test/bp21/`

   - Matched: `/bp21/`
2. `/v/test/s21/`

   - Matched: `/s21/`
3. `/v/test/21/`

   - Matched: `/21/`

I now want to stop matching if the string begins with `/cp/`, I thought this would be as simple as adding a negative lookbehind:

`/(?<!^\/cp\/)\/(bp|s)?\d+\//`

However this doesn't seem to work, instead I get the following results:

1. `/v/test/bp21/`

   - Matched: `/bp21/`
2. `/v/test/s21/`

   - Matched: `/s21/`
3. `/v/test/21/`

   - Matched: `/21/`
4. `/cp//123123/`

   - No match (desired effect)
5. `/cp/test/123123/`

   - Matched: `/123123/` - **undesired**

I'm guessing this is because I'm not specifying anything in-between the lookbehind and the main expression, but the string could contain any number of characters after `/cp/` and before `/21/` for example.

Here is the example on RegExr: https://regexr.com/3npis

I've tried loads of variations of `.*` and lazy quantifiers but I can't seem to get it there, has anyone else successfully overcome this? Thanks!

Comment: Didn’t you introduce one `/` to many here now? Your negative LBH looks for `^\/cp\/`, so effectively “(not) `/cp/` at the start.” And then after that, it goes on with `\/(bp|s)` ... I think that’s why your second last example starting with `/cp//...` works as desired, but `/cp/...` doesn’t.

Comment: Yes the 4th example is the desired outcome, but I also need the 5th example to work

Comment: @bbeckford Is it possible for `/cp/1234/` or `/cp/test/something/12345/` to exist?

Comment: @bbeckford does [`^(?!/cp/).*\K/(bp|s)?\d+/`](https://regex101.com/r/nS2Cdm/1) work for you? Are you *actually* trying to catch `bp` or `s` into the capture group or are you simply trying to match either of those? The reason I ask is that it can instead be matched if you don't need the value.

Comment: @CoffeehouseCoder It is *not* possible for `/cp/1234/` to exist but it *is* possible for `/cp/test/something/12345/` to exist

Comment: @ctwheels I'm simply looking for a boolean does it match or not. I tried your example but couldn't get it to work, thanks for trying :)

Comment: @bbeckford that's exactly how you would accomplish this.

Comment: @ctwheels I take it back - that did it! Thank you!! Please post it as an answer and I will mark it right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note the following regular expression uses a character other than `/` as a delimiter for the pattern in PHP. The regex101 link below uses `~` as the delimiter. This is to prevent the need to escape all `/` (since they're common in this regex).

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/nS2Cdm/2)

```
^(?!/cp/).*\K/(?:bp|s)?\d+/
^(?!/cp/).*/(?:bp|s)?\d+/     # If you're just doing boolean operations
^(?!/cp/).*\K/(bp|s)?\d+/     # If you want to capture bp or s
```

- `^` Assert position at the start of the line
- `(?!/cp/)` Negative lookahead ensuring `/cp/` does not follow
- `.*` Match any character any number of times
- `\K` Resets the starting point of the reported match. Any previously consumed characters are no longer included in the final match
- `/` Match this literally
- `(?:bp|s)?` Optionally match `bp` or `s`
- `\d+` Match one or more digits
- `/` Match this literally

Results:

```
/v/test/bp21/      # Matches /bp21/
/v/test/s21/       # Matches /s21/
/v/test/21/        # Matches /21/
/cp//123123/       # Does not match
/cp/test/123123/   # Does not match
```

Comment: Thanks for this!
Worth noting that for a simple preg_match I didn't require the `\K`, however if I was using this to capture the segment for my purposes I would want to include the `bp|s` and so the `?:` would not be required either

Comment: @bbeckford I've added a couple of regular expressions for what you've just specified :)